# Removing a Item from a NSOutlineView fails on child elements that aren't directly inside the root

Tags: cocoa, swift, nsoutlineview

I have a NSOutlineView and implement a remove method in my ViewController. 
When i am removing a item from the root node, it works like it should, but when i am removing a child from a node inside the root. the app crashes with a stack trace that points to outlineView.removeItemsAtIndexes

This is my code:

```
if outlineView.selectedRow >= 0 && self.selectedItem != nil {
            if let item = self.selectedItem {

                if let parentNode = dataRoot.getParentOf(item) {
                    println("REMOVE FROM \(parentNode.keyname)")

                    outlineView.removeItemsAtIndexes(NSIndexSet(index: outlineView.selectedRow - 1), inParent: parentNode, withAnimation: NSTableViewAnimationOptions.SlideUp)

                }
                dataRoot.remove(item)
                self.outlineView.reloadData()
            }
        }
```

i println the REMOVE FROM to be sure the getParentOf func works right. It does.

```
- root
    - sub-1
    - sub-2
        - sub-sub1-1
```

Removing sub-1 is OK, removing sub-sub-1 fails.

Why i can remove a item if parentNode is dataRoot, but not if it is a subnode inside dataNode?

The error is:

```
NSOutlineView error removing child indexes <NSIndexSet: 0x600000227120>[number of indexes: 1 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (9)] in parent 0x6000000af720 (which has 4 children).
```

Thank you for your help. 
ps

*** UPDATE ***

Ah ok, the Index is inside of the inParent not in the whole outline! But how to get this from selectedRow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data source should be able to find the index of an item within its parent. After all, it provided the parent's child items by index in the first place (`outlineView(_:child:ofItem:)`).

However, if you're going to tell the outline view to reload its data, then there's no point in using `removeItemsAtIndexes(_:inParent:withAnimation:)`. The main point of that method is to let the outline view know about model changes without having to reload the whole outline.

Comment: Hi ken. Thanx a lot. I see, that reload and remove is ambiguous. The way I should go is to implement a dataRoot.getIndexOfItem(root: ) method? Or should I do this inside my outlineview?

Comment: It's hard for me to know for sure without knowing how your data source and model are designed. It seems to me that it would be more appropriate to query the `parentNode` for the index of one of its children.

Comment: I gave my model two functions: getRootOf(node:) and getIndexOf(node:, inParent:). This works pretty fine. But i am not convinced about the architecture. My model is more or less a tree-list. A model have an subnodes array that can have other subnodes and so on. The implementation of the two func's inside the model, well... the functionality should be outside my data structure. I could move them to a helper-class for sure, but I can't really get the idea out of my head that this should be a UI task. But do i really want this in my ViewController - I don't think so.

Comment: This are just my Monday morning thoughts to get clear about design.Thank you very much for your help. This works, but i will go into a redesign session of my models at the end of the week.